# Render widgets to different positions on paintdevice

Tags: qt

With Qt I want to print multiple widgets onto a single DINA4-page.
Say I have 3 widgets that I want to place directly next to each other:

```
-------
|  A  |
-------
|  B  |
-------
|  C  |
-------
```

As I render them in my code below, all 3 widgets are rendered above each other at the postion of C (or even A and B are not rendered at all, I don't see it). I intended to move each widget a little bit down by the size of the last widget, to render it directly next to the last one. This seems not to work:

```
int lastWidgetHeight;
lastWidgetHeight= 0;

for (int i = 0; i < this->widgets.size(); i++){
    Wid* e = widgets.at(i);
    QWidget *printBox = e->printArea();

    // define float scaleX and scaleY [...]

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(printer);
    painter.scale(scaleX,scaleY);

    // render and translate in y-direction:
    printBox->render(&painter, QPoint(0,lastWidgetHeight));  // <-- My idea

    painter.end();

    lastWidgetHeight+= e->height();
}
```

If all 3 widgets are rendered, then how does the loop affect the position of A and B, since I create a new QPainter-Object each time?

Comment: It's unnecessary to recreate the painter every time. Simply reuse the same painter created outside of the loop. You can also set the painter translation so that the subsequent widgets are rendered at different positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your 3 elements in a layout

```
 QVVoxLayout *Vertical_layout;
 this->getLayout()->addLayout(this->Vertical_layout);
 Vertical_layout->addItem(ElementA);
 Vertical_layout->addItem(ElementB);
 Vertical_layout->addItem(ElementC);
```

and you can set the distance between them with:

```
 Vertical_layout- >setContentsMargins(left,top,right,bottom);
```

With that they will always be in their place.

Comment: They already appear like that on the screen. Of course I could try to render the whole widget that they are added to, but it also must be possible to print them separate below each other. This is what I was trying.